# How can I solve this segmentation fault error in C?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

Could you help me to solve this code? I'm writing it for academic purpose and I got some errors and segmentation fault as well. I'll appreciate it.

I'm learning stacks in C. I need to organize letters (as shown in char conteiners) according to their values in ASCII table with some rules as you can see in my last function.

To explain my code, I started it with 2 structs. Then a function is created to allocate memory, second to group elements in the stack. However, a last function to organize my array with each stack address created to solve my problem.

```
typedef struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prx;
} no_t;

typedef struct pilha {
    int altura;
    no_t *topo;
} pilha_t;

pilha_t* pilha_cria () {
    pilha_t *p = (pilha_t*)malloc(sizeof(pilha_t));

    p->altura = 0;
    p->topo = NULL;
    return p;
}

void pilha_empilha (pilha_t *p, char conteiner) {
    if (p == NULL) return;

    no_t *no = (no_t*)malloc(sizeof(no_t));
    no->dado = conteiner;
    no->prx = p->topo;
    p->topo = no;

    p->altura++;
}

int pilha_organiza (int altura, char *conteiners, int quantidade) {
    
    pilha_t *p = pilha_cria();
    pilha_empilha(p, conteiners[0]);

    pilha_t *v = pilha_cria();
    pilha_empilha(v, p);    //register P address in V array
    v->altura++;

    int k = 1, j=0;
    while (k < quantidade) {
        
        if (p->topo->dado == conteiners[k] && p->altura < altura) {
            pilha_empilha(p, conteiners[k]);
        }
        else if (p->topo->dado < conteiners[k]) {
            p++;        //mudar de posicao
            p = pilha_cria();
            pilha_empilha(p, conteiners[k]);

            pilha_empilha(v, p); //register P address in V array
            v->altura++;
        }
        else {  
            
            while (j < quantidade) {
                if (v->topo->dado > conteiners[k]) {     //SEG FAULT HERE!
                    pilha_empilha(v, conteiners[k]);
                }
                j++;
                v++;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("v altura: %d\n", v->altura);

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int altura = 6;
    char conteiners[] = "AKKEFAGCFE";
    int quantidade = strlen(conteiners);

    if (quantidade == 0) return 0;

    pilha_organiza (altura, conteiners, quantidade);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer: v->altura should be 4.
Thanks for reading it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, it is vital to start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity in small increments, testing at every step. *Never add to code that doesn't work.* If you write this much code without testing it, it will contain many bugs and they will be difficult to isolate.

Comment: `v++;` Why do you do that? `v` appears to be a pointer to a single `pilha_t`. It's not an array. Looks like that will cause `v` to become an invalid pointer and could be the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: @kaylum There is also a `p++;` before that, idk why hes doing that. Caio, can you explain why you're doing it?

Comment: You are calling pilha_empila with different kind of parameters : either pointer and char (p, conteiners[k]), either pointer and pointer (v,p) .